# My Tulsi plant has white thing

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

[image]

Can anyone help why my Tulsi (Holy Basil) plant has the white thing and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 4):

This plant has [white fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitefly).  The definitive test between this and powdery mildew which is also white is that if you shake the plant some of the adults will fly off. I normally recommend 5 ml dish soap to 1 liter water sprayed or rubbed on the leaves. Apply three times every 5 to seven days.

If you are using this plant for cooking having soap residue on the leaves will give it a bad taste so I recommend:

- isolate the plant in case the whitefly spreads
- cut all the foliate back leaving a few inches of stem
- reduce water and wait for the foliage to regrow

Comment: Thank you. I will try using vim liquid soap ?

Comment: @DeepaTiwari That will work, 5 ml to one litre of water, mix and spray or rub on leaves